# pandas group many columns to one column where every cell is a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

I have the dataframe

```
df = 
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1.  2. 3. 1. 5
8.  2. 1. 3. 8
4.  9. 1  2. 3
```

And I want to group all columns to a single list that will be the only columns, so I will get:

```
df = 
    l
[1,2,3,1,5]
[8,2,1,3,8]
[4,9,1,2,3]
```

(Shape of df was change from (3,5) to (3,1))

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
#best way:
df['l']=df.values.tolist()
#OR
df['l']=df.to_numpy().tolist()


#another way:
df['l']=df.agg(list,1)
#OR
df['l']=df.apply(list,1)
```